# Does this mean that it was the lowest price in the last eleven years?

Tags: meaning

Does this mean that it was the lowest price in eleven years or is it an idiom?

> But then the oil price dropped, and by early 2016 it had slumped
>   to an **eleven-year low**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This clearly means that the price had dropped in 2016 and it became as low as it was eleven years back. Here, in 2005. This is no idiom.